# Web application load failed

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, datasource, glassfish-3, java-ee-6

I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1 and GlassFish 3.1.

I created web application using JSF, ejb classes and JDBC data source.
xhtml pages reference backing managed beans, which call local interface functions on ejb classes which run queries through the data source, directly getting connection and executing queries.

The project builds successfully, but when I run the project, browser shows error "No data received", and browser tab title says failed to load.  I think maybe I have some missing configurations, cause when I run same project with no reference to managed beans (and hence not to ejb's and database) , there's no such message.

Frankly I got lost in what configuration files are needed for such a project, and what is needed to configure there. I saw numerous explanations, each saying something else, and I'm not clear which one is relevant here. If you could point me to some clear relevant explanation, I'd be grateful.

Do I need to configure for this project somewhere data source? ejb classes? anything else?

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

beans.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

index.xhtml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Movie Tickets Order </title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{!UserBean.loggedIn}">

            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:"></h:outputLabel>

            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{UserBean.username}"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: "></h:outputLabel>

            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{UserBean.password}"/>

        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{UserBean.login}" rendered="#{!UserBean.loggedIn}"/>

        <h:commandButton value="Logout" action="#{UserBean.logout}" rendered="#{UserBean.loggedIn}"/>

        <h:outputLink  value="EditMovie"  rendered="#{UserBean.isAdmin}"> Add/Edit Movie </h:outputLink>

</h:body>
```

UserBean

```
import TicketsEJB.UserejbLocal;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;

@Named(value = "UserBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130908L;
private String username;
private String password;
private String status;
private boolean exist = false;
private boolean loggedIn = false;
private final String statusAdmin = "admin";
private final String statusUser = "user";

@EJB
UserejbLocal userejb;

public boolean isAdmin() {
    return status.equals(statusAdmin);
}

public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return loggedIn;
}

public void login() {

    status = userejb.getUser(username, password);
    exist = (status == null) ? false : true;

    if (exist) {
        //render "Hello user"
        if (status.equals(statusAdmin)) {
            loggedIn=true;
            //render admin part: 
        }
    } else {
        //render "Sorry, wrong credentials"
    }
    password = null;
}
....
```

Userejb class:

```
@Stateful
@Local(UserejbLocal.class)
public class Userejb implements UserejbLocal {

private Connection connection = null;
private PreparedStatement getUser = null;
private PreparedStatement addUser = null;
private PreparedStatement getUserSalt = null;
private boolean exist;
private String status;
@Resource( name = "jdbc/Movies")
DataSource dataSource;


@PostConstruct
@Override
public void prepareStatements() {
    try {
        if (dataSource == null) { 
            throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");
        }
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();  
        if (connection == null) { 
            throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");
        }
        try {
            getUser = connection.prepareStatement( 
                    "SELECT STATUS  "
                    + "FROM Users"
                    + "WHERE NAMEU= ? and HASHP=?");
            addUser = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "insert into Users values ('?','?','?','?')");
            getUserSalt = connection.prepareStatement( 
                    "SELECT SALTP  "
                    + "FROM Users"
                    + "WHERE NAMEU= ? ");
        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}


    @Override
public void addUser(String name, String password, String status) {
    String salt = Security.salt();
    try {
        addUser.setString(1, name);
        addUser.setString(2, Security.hash(password + salt));
        addUser.setString(3, salt);
        addUser.setString(4, status);
        addUser.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Userejb.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
....
```

UserejbLocal interface :

```
public interface UserejbLocal {
void prepareStatements();
void addUser(String name, String password, String status);
public java.lang.String getUser(java.lang.String name, java.lang.String password);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, the problem is that it fails to access the database for some reason. Could it be because of the database password?

Comment: Your question is too broad: If it's the data layer that fails, the JSF part is confusing. A quick look at your stateful session bean: You have possibly a problem with the cached prepared statement. Try to prepare *and* execute the statement in `addUser`. In any case `prepareStatements` should not be part of the public interface.

Comment: I gave all the info because I didn't know at first where was the problem. 
But now I see the problem is in accessing the database, though I don't understand what could be the problem. I created connection pool (with javax.sql.DataSource as resource type and org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource40 as DataSource classname , and ping to it from server admin console succeeds) and also created JDBC resource with JNDI Name:jdbc/Movies name and previously created pool as pool name)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was SQLSyntaxErrorException. Just needed to look at server log (output tab , glassfish server  tab) to see what was the problem. Fixing SQL syntax rendered the page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space between `Users` and `WHERE` in your query. This is causing the query to be parsed as:

```
SELECT STATUS  FROM UsersWHERE NAMEU ...............
```